# Templating constructor for highcharts via erb

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts, erb

I am attempting to use Sinatra write json in order to render a highchart spider plot. Seems simple but I am getting an error with everything I try.

I am currently getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function58:11 (anonymous
>   function)jquery.min.js:2 m.Callbacks.jjquery.min.js:2
>   m.Callbacks.k.fireWithjquery.min.js:2 m.extend.readyjquery.min.js:2 J

However, when I copy and paste the javascript generated by Sinatra, it works: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/polar-spider/#&togetherjs=UM5qRTAt0G)

Here's my sinatra code (most relevant part at very end):

```
  get '/tasting/:id' do
      id = params[:id]
      result = {}
      tasting = Tasting.find(id)
      components = ['nose', 'berry', 'citrus', 'stonefruit', 'grassy', 'floral',
        'spicy', 'mineral', 'sweet', 'sour', 'woody', 'tannic',
        'body', 'balance', 'finish']

      chart = {}
      chart['polar'] = true
      chart['type'] = 'line'
      result['chart'] = chart

      xaxis = {}
      xaxis['categories'] = components
      xaxis['tickmarkPlacement'] = 'on'
      xaxis['lineWidth'] = 0

      yaxis = {}
      yaxis['gridLineInterpolation'] = 'polygon'
      yaxis['lineWidth'] = 0
      yaxis['min'] = 0


      legend = {}
      legend['align'] = 'right'
      legend['verticalAlign'] = 'top'
      legend['y'] = 70
      legend['layout'] = 'vertical'

      series = []
      s1 = {}
      s1['pointPlacement'] = 'on'
      s1['name'] = 'tasting'
      data = []
      for c in components
        data.push(tasting[c])
      end

      s1['data'] = data
      series.push(s1)

      result['xAxis'] = xaxis
      result['yAxis'] = yaxis
      result['legend'] = legend
      result['series'] = series

      @json = result.to_json
      erb :'show_highchart'
    end
```

show_highchart.erb:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>


<script>
$(function() {
    console.log($('#container'));
    console.log(<%= @json %>);

    $('#container').highcharts(<%= @json %>);
});
</script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Rendered html:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>


<script>
$(function() {
    console.log($('#container'));
    console.log({"chart":{"polar":true,"type":"line"},"xAxis":{"categories":["nose","berry","citrus","stonefruit","grassy","floral","spicy","mineral","sweet","sour","woody","tannic","body","balance","finish"],"tickmarkPlacement":"on","lineWidth":0},"yAxis":{"gridLineInterpolation":"polygon","lineWidth":0,"min":0},"legend":{"align":"right","verticalAlign":"top","y":70,"layout":"vertical"},"series":[{"pointPlacement":"on","name":"tasting","data":[1,3,2,2,2,3,2,2,3,2,3,3,2,2,3]}]});

    $('#container').highcharts({"chart":{"polar":true,"type":"line"},"xAxis":{"categories":["nose","berry","citrus","stonefruit","grassy","floral","spicy","mineral","sweet","sour","woody","tannic","body","balance","finish"],"tickmarkPlacement":"on","lineWidth":0},"yAxis":{"gridLineInterpolation":"polygon","lineWidth":0,"min":0},"legend":{"align":"right","verticalAlign":"top","y":70,"layout":"vertical"},"series":[{"pointPlacement":"on","name":"tasting","data":[1,3,2,2,2,3,2,2,3,2,3,3,2,2,3]}]});
});
</script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Do you load a jquery ?

Comment: I tried it both ways. But it turned out I originally loaded jquery after highcharts so it didn't work. Thanks! Dumb mistake.